# Robolectric Test for ProgressDialog in android

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, robolectric

I have 2 methods

```
public void showProgress() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoanDemandDetails.this, "", resourceUtil.getLabelById(R.string.uploading_loan_demand), true, false);
}
```

and

```
public void onHideProgressDialog() {
    progressDialog.hide();
}
```

I want to test these functions using Robolectric.

I've written a test case for `showProgress` and it passed which looks like the following.

```
@Test
public void showProgressDialog() {
    activity.showProgress();

    ProgressDialog dialog = (ProgressDialog) ShadowProgressDialog.getLatestDialog();

    assertEquals("Uploading Loan Demand...", shadowOf(dialog).getMessage());
}
```

Similarly, when I write a test case for `hideProgressDialog`, it fails.

```
@Test
public void hideProgressDialog(){
    activity.showProgress();

    activity.onHideProgressDialog();
    ProgressDialog dialog1 = (ProgressDialog) ShadowProgressDialog.getLatestDialog();
    assertFalse(dialog1.isShowing());
}
```

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, the code that checks the dialog is showing or not is being executed too fast before the dialog is actually being hidden. I would like to suggest adding an intentional `Thread.sleep` between the executions as follows.

```
@Test
public void hideProgressDialog() throws Exception {
    activity.showProgress();
    activity.onHideProgressDialog();

    // Introduce some intentional delay here
    Thread.sleep(2000); // 2 seconds delay added 

    // Now check if the tests are passing. 
    ProgressDialog dialog1 = (ProgressDialog) ShadowProgressDialog.getLatestDialog();
    assertFalse(dialog1.isShowing());
}
```

If you are using RxJava, you can use `TestScheduler` to do this in a graceful way instead of having a `Thread.sleep` in your test code.